# Get-CimInstance pipe in text file

Tags: powershell

For a client of my company, I want to create a PowerShell script to retrieve configuration information on each computer. So as a beginner in PowerShell and after a lot of research, I found 3 command lines in PowerShell which are useful to do this :

- Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_LogicalDisk
- Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Processor
- Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem

The aim now is to pipe these 3 informations to a text file or an Excel file if possible. After trying, I've just managed to export a single result that replaces another in a text file but I can't manage to add these 3, one line after the other.

I use this command to export result in file : Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_LogicalDisk | Out-File -FilePath C:\test.txt

And to add line : Add-Content -Path C:\test.txt -Value (Get-CimInstance -Classname Win32_Processor) but the result isn't conclusive.

Thank's for your help !

Comment: Don't use `Add-Content`, use `Out-File -Append`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
"win32_logicaldisk", "win32_processor", "win32_computersystem" | 
% { gcim -cl $_ } | out-file outfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine multiple statements into one pipeline with "$()":

```
$(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_LogicalDisk
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Processor
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem) | Out-File -FilePath C:\test.txt
```

Or streaming with "& {}":

```
& {Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_LogicalDisk
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Processor
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem} | Out-File -FilePath C:\test.txt
```